# Unexplained "CallFailed" exception when calling constructor function

Tags: runtime-error, rascal

i have the following method to normalize Java M3 nodes:

```
public node normalizeNodeDec(ast) {
return top-down visit (ast) {
    case \method(x, _, y, z, q) => \method(Type::short(), "methodName", y, z, q)
    case \method(x, _, y, z) => \method(Type::short(), "methodName", y, z)
    case \parameter(x, _, z) => \parameter(x, "paramName", z)
    case \vararg(x, _) => \vararg(x, "varArgName") 
    case \annotationTypeMember(x, _) => \annotationTypeMember(x, "annonName")
    case \annotationTypeMember(x, _, y) => \annotationTypeMember(x, "annonName", y)
    case \typeParameter(_, x) => \typeParameter("typeParaName", x)
    case \constructor(_, x, y, z) => \constructor("constructorName", x, y, z)
    case \interface(_, x, y, z) => \interface("interfaceName", x, y, z)
    case \class(_, x, y, z) => \class("className", x, y, z)
    case \enumConstant(_, y) => \enumConstant("enumName", y) 
    case \enumConstant(_, y, z) => \enumConstant("enumName", y, z)
    case \methodCall(x, _, z) => \methodCall(x, "methodCall", z)
    case \methodCall(x, y, _, z) => \methodCall(x, y, "methodCall", z) 
    case Type _ => lang::java::jdt::m3::AST::short()
    case Modifier _ => lang::java::jdt::m3::AST::\private()
    case \simpleName(_) => \simpleName("simpleName")
    case \number(_) => \number("1337")
    case \variable(x,y) => \variable("variableName",y) 
    case \variable(x,y,z) => \variable("variableName",y,z) 
    case \booleanLiteral(_) => \booleanLiteral(true)
    case \stringLiteral(_) => \stringLiteral("StringLiteralThingy")
    case \characterLiteral(_) => \characterLiteral("q")
}
```

But when i run this code i get the following error:
[image: Rascal error]

Does anyone know what this means and how i can solve this error? I do know that the error points exactly to the line `case \method(x, _, y, z, q) => \method(short(), "methodName", y, z, q)` and that it highligts `q`.

I am on rascal stable.

UPDATE: I changed the code accordingly but this still does not seems to solve the error see below:
updated code:

```
public node normalizeNodeDec(ast) {
return top-down visit (ast) {
    case \method(x, _, y, z, q) => \method(Type::short(), "methodName", y, z, q)
    case \method(x, _, y, z) => \method(Type::short(), "methodName", y, z)
    case \parameter(x, _, z) => \parameter(x, "paramName", z)
    case \vararg(x, _) => \vararg(x, "varArgName") 
    case \annotationTypeMember(x, _) => \annotationTypeMember(x, "annonName")
    case \annotationTypeMember(x, _, y) => \annotationTypeMember(x, "annonName", y)
    case \typeParameter(_, x) => \typeParameter("typeParaName", x)
    case \constructor(_, x, y, z) => \constructor("constructorName", x, y, z)
    case \interface(_, x, y, z) => \interface("interfaceName", x, y, z)
    case \class(_, x, y, z) => \class("className", x, y, z)
    case \enumConstant(_, y) => \enumConstant("enumName", y) 
    case \enumConstant(_, y, z) => \enumConstant("enumName", y, z)
    case \methodCall(x, _, z) => \methodCall(x, "methodCall", z)
    case \methodCall(x, y, _, z) => \methodCall(x, y, "methodCall", z) 
    case Type _ => Type::short()
    case Modifier _ => Modifier::\private()
    case \simpleName(_) => \simpleName("simpleName")
    case \number(_) => \number("1337")
    case \variable(x,y) => \variable("variableName",y) 
    case \variable(x,y,z) => \variable("variableName",y,z) 
    case \booleanLiteral(_) => \booleanLiteral(true)
    case \stringLiteral(_) => \stringLiteral("StringLiteralThingy")
    case \characterLiteral(_) => \characterLiteral("q")
}
```

Updated error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CallFailed` happens when the actual parameter types do not line up with formal parameter types of a function. In this case it's a constructor function which fails to apply because of this.

Unfortunately there is no type-checker in the current stable release to help us realize that there are two version of `short()` in the current scope, of which silently the "first" one is chosen! There is one from `Type` and one from `TypeSymbol`. If it picks the wrong one, you have a match failed because `Type` and `TypeSymbol` are incompatible.

To fix, please use: `Type::short()` for `short()` and everything should be fine again.

That goes for all instances of types in your code so:

`case Type _ => lang::java::jdt::m3::AST::short()` should be `case Type _ => Type::short()` and `case Modifier _ => lang::java::jdt::m3::AST::\private()` should be `case Modifier _ => Modifier::\private()`

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response! I changed the code and got kind of the same error. I updated the question with the new error.

Comment: I see ;-) I changed the answer.

Comment: Hi Thanks again for your response. The solution still did not solve the problem. I really can't figure out why rascal does not accept the method parameters to create a new method node :(

Comment: I tested the code and it worked for me. Maybe try and restart the console and even eclipse. Sometimes we have an update problem. Keep me posted!

Comment: I have this problem on my desktop and laptop. I just did a full clean install on my desktop and i still seem to have this issue. Is it possible for me to send the source code to you to see if you get the error?

Comment: I'm happy to help. Might take some time though cuz I'm not fully at work now. Email me? Either Google will help or ask your prof my address if you are in a course right now.

Comment: see https://github.com/usethesource/rascal/issues/1293 where a bug was fixed. Type selectors on the pattern match side were sometimes ignored.